# ISO 8061 dmy failing to parse after a certain row at change of date

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, parsing

i have a column of dates in mm/dd/yyyy and am trying to use dmy() to convert and store them in a new column in ISO format. it works for the first 15k rows, but then stops working for the rest of the file, with the error "Warning message: 2786262 failed to parse." i looked through the file to see where it stops working and noticed that it stops working in the row where it changes from 4/12/2014 to 4/13/2014. any idea what i might be doing wrong here?

```
uber14$DateISO <- dmy(uber14$Date)
```

> Warning message:
>    2786262 failed to parse.

```
uber14$DateISO <- format(lubridate::dmy(uber14$Date), "%b@%B")
```

> Warning message:
>    2786262 failed to parse.

```
uber14[15073,10]
[1] "2014-12-04"

uber14[15073,8]
[1] "4/12/2014"

uber14[15074,8]
[1] "4/12/2014"

uber14[15075,8]
[1] "4/13/2014"

uber14[15075,10]
[1] NA

uber14[15074,10]
[1] "2014-12-04"

dmy(uber14[15075,8])
[1] NA
```

Comment: If you have data in format `mm/dd/yyyy` would it be useful to use `mdy` instead of `dmy`

Comment: Seems like you may have a mix of d/m/y, m/d/y and y-m-d based on the examples shown.

Comment: If the dates are in different formats, one option is `parse_date_time` or `anytime::anydate`

Comment: @neilfws sorry for any confusion but all the dates in col 8 are in the form that i want to convert to ISO, which i am trying to record to col 10. when i check the results, col 10 behaves correctly through 4/12, but then suddenly stops working for 4/13 onwards (there are hundreds of rows per day).

Comment: @akrun i'm not sure about that...the dates i am trying to convert are all in the same format of mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: In that case, why you used `dmy` as in my first comment it is dd/mm/yyyy.  Instead it should be `mdy`

Comment: thanks @akrun -- sorry for the confusion on my end. that solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to using `dmy` for `mm/dd/yyyy` format.  It should be `mdy`

```
library(lubridate)
uber14$DateISO <- mdy(uber14$Date)
```